# When did the Pakistan army used tank for the first time during the 1971 Bangladesh war?

Tags: war, asia, pakistan, south-asia

I would like to know the first recorded case of usage of tank in the Bangladesh war which took place in 1971.

Comment: As they had tanks, I would assume they used them. Or do you have any reason to assume they did not use the tanks from the start? A little more context here would be helpful to understand the question.

Comment: @LennartRegebro, One of my friends claimed that they didn't use tanks until India got involved. Later, I got two records of using tanks one on April 23rd and another on September 20th both before India got involved.  Thanks anyway.

Comment: @LennartRegebro depending on the terrain, using tanks might not be a good idea. A lot of Bangladesh being rather boggy makes it less than ideal tank country...

Comment: I have pledged to downvote any question that asks for historical analysis of "my friend said".  Those kind of questions are generally answerable from  wikipedia or google.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 20 Baluch with some tanks had secured the area immediately around the cantonment in the morning.

This is the 26th of March during [Operation Searchlight](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Searchlight#March_26), the start of the war. As I suspected, they had tanks and used them from the beginning.

Answer (score 2):

In the 1971 Bangladesh war in the eastern theaters pakistan had 1 armored regiment which consist of 75 US made M24 Chaffee tanks.

Tanks was used in Dakha during operation searchlite on March 25th. Chittagong also saw some tank actions dring the same operation.

During the operation searchlite which started on March 25 to April 10 Pakistani Army used Tanks to reduce the morale of the peoples of East Pakistan.

In the western Theaters, Pakistani tanks met an ill fate during the [battle of Longewala](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Longewala).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there was a tank battle and some of the Pakistani tanks were capture by the Indian army. There were traitors in the Pakistan who was involved in breaking the East Pakistan with the help of the Indian army and government.
The M24 chaffee tanks took part in the operation that was started in march and ended in May. You may refer further at
[Men In Black-The Armored Corps Of The Pakistan Army](http://www.pakarmyranks.com/2016/03/armoured-corps-of-pakistan-army.html)

Comment: When and where was the tank battle?